# how to save different page info to the same tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

That is my problem. I just want the info show it at the same cell.But I don't know how to fix it.it's from different page.(777777 & Tom) 
it seems like always insert a new cell when I input another page.

```
            switch type {
            case .insert:
                if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
                }
            case .delete:
                if let indexPath = indexPath {
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                }
            case .update:
                if let indexPath = indexPath {
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                }
            default:
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            if let fetchedObjects = controller.fetchedObjects {
                visitors = fetchedObjects as! [VisitorMO]
            }
        }
        func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZWvS.gif)

Comment: show how VisitorMO realized

Comment: Hi Anton Novoselov,
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<VisitorMO> = VisitorMO.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        }

Comment: if let AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate){
            let context = AppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            fetchResultController.delegate = self
            do{try fetchResultController.performFetch()
                if let fetchedObjects = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects{
                    visitors = fetchedObjects
                }}catch{
    print(error)
            }}

Comment: make another picture, show in this another picture how exactly all text labels have to be located

Comment: Hi Anton Novoselov,
I uploaded one more picture. please noted that.
My project had 3 View-controller. A will show all user information.
B & C just for user input their information.

Comment: I expected it will show all information in the same cell..but it doesn't work.
Please let me know how to fix it...thanks so much!!!

Comment: show numberOfRows, numberOfSections, and cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdenitifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdenitifier, for: indexPath)
        as! VisitorTableViewCell
cell.NameLabel.text = visitor.name
        cell.CompanyLabel.text = visitor.company
        cell.PhonenumberLabel.text = visitor.phonenumber
        cell.JobnumberLabel.text = visitor.jobnumber
return cell
    }

Comment: override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.isActive {
            return searchResults.count
        } else {
            return visitors.count
        }
}

Comment: I created answer. Try this. And please add this code snippets to your question (press Edit button), not to comments, because it's rather hard to read them in one line :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where did you get visitor, that you use in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
seems like you get wrong visitor. Try to edit your cellforrow method with this:

```
let visitor = (searchController.isActive) ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : visitors[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Anton Novoselov.
I still can't solve this issues...may I have your mail?
I want to send my project to you or do you know how can share my project?
Thank you sooooo much!!!

Comment: Could you upload your project to github and provide link to ti? I think it would be better, more people will be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Anton Novoselov I uploaded my project in google drive. could you open it?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3H5t5nGJITYeTAtcHRzV3QxOWM/view?usp=sharing

and please kindly review below photo.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZWvS.gif